# Using system clock for accurate idle timeout warning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a modal which will alert users of a pending logout due to idle time.  Overall it works, but I notice the timer is not 100% accurate.  I know there are issues with setInterval and accuracy.  I still seeing discrepancies and will welcome a suggestion on how to improve my code.

```
var sessionTimeoutPeriod = 240;
var state = "L";
var timeoutPeriod = sessionTimeoutPeriod * 1000;
var logout = Math.floor(timeoutPeriod / 60000);
var idleInterval;

if (state == "L" || state == "O" || state == "C") {
var idleTime = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        console.log("The mouse moved, idle time = " + idleTime);
    });
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        console.log("A key was pressed, idle time = " + idleTime);
    });


    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

});

function timerIncrement() {

  idleTime++;
    console.log("The total idle time is "+idleTime+  " minutes.");

    if (idleTime >= 1) {
    console.log("The modal will fire if idle time = " +idleTime);
        var modal = new window.AccessibleModal({
        mainPage: $('#main'),
            overlay: $('#overlay').css('display', 'block'),
            modal: $('#modal-session-timeout'),
            prevFocus: $('#main')
        });

         modal.show();

         $('#modal-overlay').removeClass('opened');

        $('.js-timeout-refresh, .xClose').click(function() {
            modal.hide();
            $('#overlayTY').css('display', 'none');
            idleTime = 0;

            console.log("The total idle time is "+idleTime+  " minutes.");
        });
        $('.js-timeout-session-end').click(function() {
            modal.hide();
            $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
            endSession();
        });
        console.log(idleTime);
    }
    if (idleTime == logout) { // 9 minutes
        endSession();
    }

    var endSession = function() {
        document.location.replace(logoutPageUrl);
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what your issue is.  What's your idle timeout intended to be?  Looks like it's meant to be 4 minutes (?)   You're only checking if idle once a minute, so won't ever be more accurate than a minute - nothing to do with how "accurate" setTimeout is (which is in the order of 5ms, which would be far too short as an idle timeout).  So what's the problem?

Comment: For the purpose of debugging, I set the session to end after 4 minutes of inactivity.  The interval is set to one minute.  The expected behavior is the modal will appear every minute, this is happening on the first iteration, but any other varies between a few seconds over or before the one minute mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the interval to determine how much time has passed, you could validate how much time has passed manually by comparing the current time against the time since last activity.

This way you can increase the checking interval without having to modify the code. The discrepancy will never be higher then then the interval timeout now, the discrepancy will also not change incrementally, it will always be lower or equal to the interval ( in worst case scenario ).

Here is a basic example.

```
var sessionTimeoutPeriod = 240;
var timeoutPeriod = sessionTimeoutPeriod * 1000;
var oneMinute = 60000;
var showIdlePopUpTimeOut = oneMinute * 2;
var lastActivity = new Date();

function getIdleTime() {
    return new Date().getTime() - lastActivity.getTime();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        console.log("The mouse moved, idle time = " + getIdleTime());
        lastActivity = new Date();
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        console.log("A key was pressed, idle time = " + getIdleTime());
        lastActivity = new Date();
    });

    setInterval(checkIdleTime, 5000);
});

function endSession() {
    document.location.replace(logoutPageUrl);
};

function checkIdleTime() {
    var idleTime = getIdleTime();
    console.log("The total idle time is " + idleTime / oneMinute + " minutes.");

    if (idleTime > showIdlePopUpTimeOut) {
        var modal = new window.AccessibleModal({
            mainPage: $('#main'),
            overlay: $('#overlay').css('display', 'block'),
            modal: $('#modal-session-timeout'),
            prevFocus: $('#main')
        });

        modal.show();

        $('#modal-overlay').removeClass('opened');

        $('.js-timeout-refresh, .xClose').click(function () {
            modal.hide();
            $('#overlayTY').css('display', 'none');
            lastActivity = new Date();
        });
        $('.js-timeout-session-end').click(function () {
            modal.hide();
            $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
            endSession();
        });
        console.log(lastActivity);
    }
    if (idleTime > timeoutPeriod) { // 4 minutes
        endSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: When I increase the oneMinute variable to two minutes, the modal is not firing, it jumps to the end session function after two minutes.  I tried changing the checkIdleTime to 10,000 also to fix, but same result.  The idle time will be five minutes, but I am testing at a lower time.  What do I need to do?

Comment: @user1725382 don't change the oneMinute variable to two minutes, it's used in multiple places. Create a separate twoMinute variable and then use that where you wanna use it.

Comment: @user1725382 I updated the code to include the `showIdlePopUpTimeOut` to increase the timeout when the idle dialog will show. Does that help ?

Comment: Thanks for sir for your explanation and help.  I added another variable for two minutes and that worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your function "timerIncrement" checks the difference every minute after loading the page, so you will never get exact 1 minute after last activity.Changing interval from 60000 to 1000 will solve the issue.

You don't even need to calculate diff, you can just reset timeout every time there is activity. like this:

```
$(this).on("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
        clearInterval(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setTimeout(functionThatExecutesAfter1minInactivity, 60000);
    });
```

Comment: Probably want `setTimeout` if you do it this way

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes you are right I've just copy/pasted the code and that's why I got error. I'll update